# when we use SOAP web-services?

Tags: android, iphone, soap, service, web

i am a beginner of web services i know some concept of web services, SOAP based, in mobile application development, like iphone and android, but i just can't understand for which particular situation we use soap?

Comment: do you want to create a service or you want to use any existing service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOAP can be a real pain. I really recommend using something like JSON if possible. If you can't and you are stuck using SOAP then [this](http://sudzc.com/) might help you. Its a handy code generator that allows you to import the SOAP service's WSDL file (the file that describes the service) and it generates objective-c classes.

But be aware it does not handle WSDL's well that import XSD's :(

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your platform, you can use SOAP for Remote Procedure Calls (for example).

Answer (score 0):

you should use SOAP, when u are exposing services from server. These service will server the request. You will define the rule(protocol/service) using SOAP. Later any client and follow the rules to use the services..
to give a simple example-- You can provide service which provide time and publish schema.
Later anyone who want to use this service will adhere to the rule (schema) and invoke.

It can be involve from client which can be mobile, any embedded device or browser